# To filter string using subset in R

Tags: r, filter

I have this data.

```
structure(list(val = "108_front_outside, lake, 106_front_later"),
row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to filter something using subset of `val`.
The subset of `val` is like `"108_front_outside"`, `"lake"`, `"106_front_later"`, `"108_front_out, lake"` ... (totaling 8 components)

If it works well, A = "106_front_later, lake" would be filtered,

but B = "lake, others" would be not filtered because it contains the other component ("others").

How should I approach this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I get you correct, you can try the following with a combination of grepl and strsplit on ",". If there's more to you, you should explain the logic of your filtering:

```
val = "108_front_outside, lake, 106_front_later"
allwords = unlist(strsplit(val,","))

test = c("108_front_outside", "lake", "106_front_later", 
"108_front_out, lake", "lake, others")

sapply(test,function(i)all(sapply(strsplit(i,",")[[1]],function(j)any(grepl(j,allwords)))))

108_front_outside                lake     106_front_later 
               TRUE                TRUE                TRUE 
108_front_out, lake        lake, others 
               TRUE               FALSE
```